# ASP.NET MVC application return 503 (Service Unavailable) error, Deployed in IIS with https protocol

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis, iis-8.5

In my case `http://localhost` was working, but `https://localhost` throws a HTTP 503 Internal server error.

1. I am consuming an API using the http request
2. If an API response is received within 15 seconds, it means it worked
3. If you exceed 15 seconds, you will receive a 503 (Service Unavailable) error

I have implemented the following solutions, but they do not work.

Solution #1:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="300" enable="true" 
     maxQueryStringLength="32768" maxUrlLength="65536" 
     maxRequestLength="4096" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" 
     targetFramework="4.5" /> 
<sessionState mode="InProc" stateNetworkTimeout="40" timeout="2400" />
<sessionState mode="InProc" stateNetworkTimeout="30" />
```

Solution #2

[image]

Solution #3

[image]

If there is any other way to resolve this solution, please let me know.

Comment: TLS is used with HTTPS (not HTTP)  and is performed before the HTTP request is sent to establish an encrypted connection.  When TLS fails a timeout usually occurs.  You error is due to the timeout and you are not getting a real HTTP response.  When TLS fails the HTTP request is never sent.

Comment: For HTTPS to work the server needs to be configurate to accept HTTPS and a common certificate needs to be loaded in both server and client.  Sometimes you can fix by turning off proxy in client.  It may be the proxy is failing.  Other times it is a certificate issue.  Certificates are stored in the user stores and having the profile false may be disabling the stores where certificate is loaded.

Comment: Verify your site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html in case the HTTPS requests landed on the wrong site.

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 503 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Still facing same issue. If API Response time exceed 15 seconds, receive a 503 (Service Unavailable) error. Any solution regarding this.?

Answer (score 0):

503 error common cause is the application crash, in addition to using [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7), you should set debugdiag rules to collect dump for application crash and analysis the dump for the crash reason.

About how to capturing them with dumps, you need to debug the cause using IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool, this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.